# Trying to add elements of an array together

Tags: javascript, arrays, sum, addition, reduce

I am trying to get input into an array using a do while loop until the user enters a blank or 0 then am trying to add all the elements within that array together however it returns them in string form.

I have tried using `parseInt()` in multiple places however it usually makes the code not work at all.

```
document.getElementById('while').addEventListener('click', stats);
document.getElementById('while').addEventListener('click', reduction);

var input_array = [];
var value = 0;

function stats() {
  do {
    var number = prompt('Enter a Number');
    var array = input_array.push(number);

    document.getElementById('out2').innerHTML = "[" + input_array + "]";
  } while (value != number);
}

function array_sum(total, num) {
  return total + num;
}

function reduction(item) {
  document.getElementById('out3').innerHTML = input_array.reduce(array_sum);
}
```

Comment: What is `while`? A button? Is `out2` and `out3` just `<div>s`? Can you include the HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you simply `parseInt` before you push the value to the array you would get numbers in the array and all works as expected:

```js
let input_array = [];
let value = 0

function stats() {
  do {
    var number = prompt('Enter a Number');
    var array = input_array.push(parseInt(number));  // <-- parse here
  } while (value != number);
}

stats()  // show the prompt etc

function array_sum(total, num) {
  return total + num
}

console.log(input_array.reduce(array_sum))
```

I only posted the js part without the html just to give you an example that it works as expected.